# SOA Architecture, Android and Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4jclient

I am working on scientific project and i am currently studying the possibility to use graph databases.

The software architecture that we developed is service oriented with android clients.

I want to know if Neo4j can be used in my case and the most important if i can execute Cypher requests from Android.

Cheers

Comment: I think you can use the REST API of Neo4J from Android (sending `POST` requests) or build your own REST API business-based - Usually the latter is preferred...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MarcoCI mentioned you can emit Cypher queries via REST. Neo4j therefore has the [transactional Cypher endpoint](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-transactional.html) and the [legacy Cypher endpoint](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-cypher.html).

Another idea would be to encapsulate your actions on a use-case level within [unmanaged extensions](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) and let your Android client trigger those. Unmanaged extensions are basically java code deployed to the Neo4j server that expose new REST endpoints. Within its implementation you might use Cypher or core API.

Comment: Thanks Stefan and @Marco for your answers.